# How to notify user about room booking status?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a meeting room booking system which allow user to book meeting rooms for single and multiple dates and time slots.

I have created the following table with sample data.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
roomno | dtfrm      | dtto       | tmfrm    | tmto     | 
--------------------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-11 | 2019-07-11 | 07:00:00 | 10:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-12 | 2019-07-14 | 11:00:00 | 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-13 | 2019-07-13 | 10:00:00 | 11:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-14 | 2019-07-14 | 07:00:00 | 09:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

with the following code I am able to print the dates and times on which the rooms are busy on the basis of user input.

```
 // this is user input
 $dfrm = "2019-07-11";
 $dto = "2019-07-14";
 $tmfrm = "07:00:00";
 $tmto = "10:30:00";
 $roomid = "room1";

 $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
 $result = $con->query( "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE dtfrm<='$dto' AND dtto>='$dfrm' AND roomno='$roomid' ORDER BY dtfrm" );

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     if($row['tmfrm']<$tmto && $row['tmto']>$tmfrm)  {
         echo "<br>Busy on: " . $row['dtfrm'] . " | " . $row['dtto'] . " | " . $row['tmfrm'] . " | " . $row['tmto'] ;
     }
  }
```

Following is the output:

```
Busy on: 2019-07-11 | 2019-07-11 | 07:00:00 | 10:00:00
Busy on: 2019-07-13 | 2019-07-13 | 10:00:00 | 11:00:00
Busy on: 2019-07-14 | 2019-07-14 | 07:00:00 | 09:00:00
```

In the above code how can I generate an alert message to tell user that he cannot book the room on his specified date/time because the few time slots are not available and also like to notify user that room is available for booking if it is. the message should be printed once after code execution. I would also like to ask if there is a need to improve the efficiency and accuracy of my code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any problem in writing the code to accomplish your requirement?

Comment: @Nico Haase yes I have tried the above PHP code. But I am not sure if my table structure and code is perfect and I am getting trouble in writing code that notify user about availability/non-availability of rooms?

Comment: i suggest you to validate before inserting the data. and show available slots to users.. otherwise your user will be escapticle

Comment: @devpro ok. should i need a table to explicitly define time slots, or how can i do that any clue. also remember that i want to allow user to book room for any number of minutes greater than 30 mins. what is your suggestion?

Comment: yes, show only available slots to your users... slot which not available just display "Error message: slot not available" ..

Comment: @devpro great! do i also need to modify table structure as per suggestion in following answer?

Comment: use a column for saving status, if slot available, make it active status if slot not available just put 0... so you can play with 1/0 bit

Comment: ok and what about having two date fields, is it ok to have?